# How To Make A Multiline Data Label In A Bar Chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, bar-chart

This may seem like a issue that is easy to solve but I have not been able to solve it. Basically, I have a bar chart on a html web page. Using the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting to create the charts. What I want to do is change the look of the label. An idea of how my label looks like is: "M: 312 A: 321 S: 432". What I would like to do is make them on top of one another, not side by side. So "M: ..." will be the first line then the others. So three lines in total. Is there anyway I can do that?

Code:

```
    Chart1.Visible = true;
            DataTableReader datareader = table.CreateDataReader();
            Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(datareader, "FunctionGroup", "Date", "AverageGrading", "");
            Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend");
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Period of feedback";
            Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Average grade";
            Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
            Chart1.Legends[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            Chart1.Width = 1000;
            Chart1.Height = 600;

            ArrayList listOfStDev = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList listOfMed = new ArrayList();

            foreach (DateTime date in listofdates)
            {
                listOfStDev.Add(dbmanager.GetStdDevAppraisalForFunction(section, functionlist, date, questionID));
                listOfMed.Add(GetMedianFunctionViaSectionCount(section, functionlist, date, questionID));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Chart1.Series.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < Chart1.Series[i].Points.Count; k++)
                {
                    Chart1.Series[i].Points[k].Label = "A: " + "#VALY" + " S: " + Convert.ToDouble(listOfStDev[k]).ToString("F") + " M: " + Convert.ToDouble(listOfMed[k]).ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can simply add a new line character in your label string, like this: `Label="A: #VAL\nS: #VALX\nM: #INDEX"`.

Comment: thanks! that worked @jstreet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" Label="A: #VAL\nS: #VALX\nM: #INDEX">
                <Points>
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="1" YValues="10" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="2" YValues="20" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="3" YValues="30" />
                </Points>
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisY>
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX>
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

[image]